# Detect an ad in a webpage

Tags: ads

I need to collect display ads. Is there an API /plugin which already does this?

I am trying to detect an ad on the page and download it. I tried to look how different  ad blockers do this.

Typically ad blockers maintain a list of sites from which ads are shown and block them. I couldn't figure it out how are they doing it.
So can anyone let me know some ideas to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using [the PHP Document Object Model](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) and defining the patterns that define an ad.